# Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform on my windows

Tags: apache-spark

I have installed java 64bit on my windows, i have created dummy text file to test my spark on my pycharm.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
someFile = "dummy.txt"
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SimpleApp").getOrCreate()
print(spark.read.text(someFile).count())
```

Later on, it returned me with such message.

```
C:\Users\jinfe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\jinfe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\pysparkdemo.py 
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/01/20 00:44:39 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When i google this issue online, it all states due to wrong installation of 32 bit java. However, did installed the 64 bit java, can anyone assist with my problem

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html#Supported_Platforms

Comment: @DaveNewton That doesn't answer how to use Windows

Comment: @OneCricketeer It doesn’t need to: it addresses why the native Hadoop libraries aren’t loading, which was the question.

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, there was no real "question", but we can assume the question would be "how to make the warning disappear", which that link doesn't really address on how to compile the native libraries for a Windows host.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Because you don't, as the link states :shrug: (Although I'd swear I remember people doing it; idk... Ah, here, maybe: https://github.com/songdongsheng/hadoop-native)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ah, yep, appears to be doable (and doesn't seem **that** onerous if one is a Windows-y person)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore that warning. Your code printed `3`, the number of lines in the file, and ended successfully (exit code 0)